# How to get screenshot saved path by Cocos2d-x on android

Tags: android, save, gallery, cocos2d-x, screenshot

I use saveToFile method to save screenshot, and I check CCLOG, it shows /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files/xxx.png

However, when I use Java to get this file, it says "No such file or directory"....
What can I do?

Comment: try to save it in SDcard and then access

Comment: this is the part that I failed, I can open a new folder on SDcard but When I pass the "file path" from C++ to Java in order to save to gallery, it returns an error said NullPointerException...

Comment: File f = new File(filePath);
 //f.createNewFile();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    try 
    {
     f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        

    } 

this is the code I wrote.... I'm not familiar with Java....

Comment: I can create a sprite by the "saveToFile" path in C++, but I can't find the image file on the device by data/data/..... strange=.=

Comment: use `getWritablePath()` This returns where files are written.

Comment: it returned data/data/com.xxx.xxx, but I can't see the file or even folder anywhere....

Comment: I used this code to show my image to gallery but the date and time is 1970-01-01-8:00 <code>Uri a=Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mInstance.getContentResolver(), imageBitmap, "Title", ""));</code>

How can I change back to current date and Time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently, cocos2dx never creates the writable path directory so the screenshot doesn't get saved.

My solution was to, instead of calling `CCRenderTexture::saveToFile`, copy its implementation and manually save the file to a different path:

```
std::string MyClass::takeScreenshot(CCScene* scene) {
    cocos2d::CCSize screenSize = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    cocos2d::CCRenderTexture* tex = cocos2d::CCRenderTexture::create(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    tex->setPosition(ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));

    //use a different dir than cocos default writable path
    std::string filename = "/sdcard/Android/data/screenshot.png";

    tex->begin();
    scene->getParent()->visit();
    cocos2d::CCImage* img = tex->newCCImage(true);
    img->saveToFile(filename.c_str(), true);
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(img);
    tex->end();

    return filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. When I try `renderTexture->saveToFile` method, I can't submit path to java. No matter, I used `getWritablePath()` or set the path directly `"/sdcard/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/snapshot.jpg"`.
I try also to solve this problem on the advice of [Facundo Olano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993769/facundo-olano). But `CCImage` compose only solid black image.
Finally I combine this two methods. First, I make an image by `renderTexture->saveToFile`:

```
void MyScene::pressFaceBook()
{
    ...
    RenderTexture* renderTexture = RenderTexture::create(sharedImage->getBoundingBox().size.width, sharedImage->getBoundingBox().size.height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);
    renderTexture->begin();
    sharedImage->visit();
    renderTexture->end();
    renderTexture->saveToFile("snapshot.jpg", Image::Format::JPG);
    const std::string fullpath = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + "snapshot.jpg";
    sharedImage->setVisible(false);
    this->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(2.0f),
                                     CallFunc::create(std::bind(&MyScene::shareFaceBook, this, fullpath)),
                                     NULL));
}
```

And then I use `initWithImageFile` with the transferred file name:

```
void MyScene::shareFaceBook(const std::string& outputFile)
{
    const std::string joutputFile = "/sdcard/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/snapshot.jpg";
    cocos2d::Image* img = new Image;
    img->initWithImageFile(fullpath);
    img->saveToFile(joutputFile);
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(img);
    singleton->shareFaceBook(joutputFile);
}
```

A delay of 2 seconds is needed to capture the screenshot.
Of course, instead com.xxx.xxx you must substitute your app name.