# Read Write file to android error with cocos2dx (v3.6)

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to store game stage status into a file with Cocos2d-x (v3.6). But it works in iOS but not in Android. Here is the code i'm using. could anyone please tell me what's wrong i'm doing?

I get the file path from FileUtils and then write and read "StageStat" object as binary. simple.

```
std::string path = FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath();
file = path + "stagestatus.txt";
// write 
FILE *fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "wb");
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        fwrite(&stages.at(i), sizeof(StageStat), 1, fp);
}
fclose(fp);
// read
FILE *fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fread(&ss, sizeof(StageStat), 1, fp);
        stages.push_back(ss);
}
fclose(fp)
return stages;
```

I also tried `path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mygame.game/stat.txt"`  as hardcoded path

Comment: Have you checked return string of `FileUtils::getWritablePath();` ? Where does it point to ?

Comment: yes i tried. it points to '/data/data/com.myapp.xxx/files/'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but `FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath() + "fileName.txt";` doesn't work in Android, only in iOS. I used the hardcoded path

```
string path= "/sdcard/Android/data/com.myCompany.myGame/fileName.txt";
```

Try it, it should work.

Comment: what if i want to write on the main memory not to the sdcard?

Comment: I really don't know. But it's the only way that worked for me in Cocos. I tested it on a device without the sdcard. Real path was `Android/data/...` , but still in the application I wrote the path `/sdcard/Android/data/...` I decribed this method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31926744/5177476)

Comment: :( doesn't work for me :( 
its creating the file but data read is not how expected

Comment: It's strange. But I was sending data to the java part and read them in AppActivity.  Do you read them in the native part, or in the Cocos? Try to move the reading method to the AppActivity, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Maby this wil help to find the problem:

```
fp = fopen(FileUtils::getInstance()->getSuitableFOpen(filePath).c_str(), "wb");
CC_BREAK_IF(nullptr == fp);
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the code and it works, I took the image from the server and saved it

```
if (!response)
{
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - No Response");
    return;
}

log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %lu", response->getResponseCode());

if (!response->isSucceed())
{
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response failed");
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
    return;
}


log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %s", response->getResponseDataString());


std::vector<char>* buffer = response->getResponseData();
const char* file_char = buffer->data();
log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %s", file_char);
Image* image = new  Image();
image->initWithImageData(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&(buffer->front())), buffer->size());
Texture2D* texture = new  Texture2D();
texture->initWithImage(image);
Sprite* sprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(texture);
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2));
addChild(sprite);

log("onHttpRequestCompleted height %f", sprite->getContentSize().height);


if (response->isSucceed()) {
    auto data = response->getResponseData();
    FILE* fp = fopen(yyy.png", "wb");
    
    if (fp)
    {
        
        log("berhasil");
        fwrite(&(data->front()), 1, data->size(), fp);
        fclose(fp);
        sprite->setTexture("yyy.png");
        
    }
    
}
```